# Extracting json data using beautifulsoup and requests

Tags: python, django, django-templates, beautifulsoup, django-views

Facing a weird issue for a while now.
I attempted with many ways but still not able to get around the issue. 
I have the following class based view, which has a get_context_data() and will process a given city's weather. and from the returned json I need to extract correct informations that I wanna use, however, I'm struggling to have it done correctly.
When I check my template context rendering using the django-debug-toolbar, I'm able to see all the data from the json, but when I'm in the actual template in the browser I'm seeing some weird things.
Here's my code:

```
class FetchWeather(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'forecastApp/pages/weather.html'

    request_post = None

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        url = 'http://weather.news24.com/sa/cape-town'
        city = 'cape town'
        url_request = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url_request.content, 'html.parser')
        city_list = soup.find(id="ctl00_WeatherContentHolder_ddlCity")
        print(soup.head)
        city_as_on_website = city_list.find(text=re.compile(city, re.I)).parent
        cityId = city_as_on_website['value']
        json_url = "http://weather.news24.com/ajaxpro/TwentyFour.Weather.Web.Ajax,App_Code.ashx"

        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
            'Host': 'weather.news24.com',
            'Origin': 'http://weather.news24.com',
            'Referer': url,
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/48.0.2564.82 Chrome/48.0.2564.82 Safari/537.36',
            'X-AjaxPro-Method': 'GetCurrentOne'}

        payload = {
            "cityId": cityId
        }
        request_post = requests.post(json_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
        print(request_post.content)
        data = re.sub(r"new Date\(Date\.UTC\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)\)\)", convert_date, request_post.text)
        data = data.strip(";/*")
        data = json.loads(data)
        context["cityId"] = data
        return context
```

and those are the screen shots of the actual template and the analyse from deug-toolbar:
[image: normal template view[![debug toolbar]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXo0s.png)

SO in fact, all I need form this json in Forecasts:

```
{
  'CountryName': 'South Africa',
  '__type': 'TwentyFour.Services.Weather.Objects.CurrentOneReport, TwentyFour.Services.Weather, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null',
  'MarineReport': None,
  'TimeZone': '2',
  'Location': {
    '__type': 'TwentyFour.Services.Weather.Objects.Location, TwentyFour.Services.Weather, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null',
    'Forecasts': [
      {
        'DayLight': 'D',
        'WindDirection': '161',
        '__type': 'TwentyFour.Services.Weather.Objects.Forecast, TwentyFour.Services.Weather, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null',
        'SkyDescriptor': '1',
        'Date': '2016-01-27T22:00:00',
        'Rainfall': '*',
        'Icon': '1',
        'WindDirectionDescription': 'South',
        'Visibility': None,
        'TemperatureDescription': 'Mild',
        'HighTemp': '24',
        'TemperatureDescriptor': '8',
        'BeaufortDescriptor': 'Fresh breeze',
        'Cached': False,
        'PrecipitationDescriptor': '',
        'Snowfall': '*',
        'DaySegment': None,
        'ShortWeekDay': 'Sun',
        'DaySequence': 1,
        'WindSpeed': '34',
        'WeekDay': 'Sunday',
        'Sky': 'Sunny',
        'PrecipitationProbability': '0',
        'Precipitation': '',
        'WindDirectionAbreviated': 'S',
        'FormattedDate': 'Sun, Feb 28',
        'Segment': None,
        'Beaufort': '5',
        'Description': 'Sunny. Mild.',
        'IconName': 'sunny',
        'Temperature': None,
        'DewPoint': '14',
        'Air': 'Breezy',
        'Humidity': '55',
        'UV': 'High',
        'Comfort': '25',
        'LowTemp': '18',
        'DayOfWeek': 1,
        'AirDescription': '13'
      }
    ],
    'City': '77107',
    'Cached': False,
    'CityName': 'Cape Town'
  }
```

is to extract low temp, high temp and date, using beautifulsoup

Comment: Don't completely understand your question. If data is in json format, why do you need BeautifulSoup?

Comment: I was having very similiar problem, I switched to python goose instead

Comment: maybe I'm using the wrong approach but I want be able to extract data from the json extracted after having used beautifulsoup @warmoverflow

Comment: BeautifulSoup is for HTML. You have JSON; why do you think you need BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like Beautiful soup is used to retrieve the `city_id` for the relevant city.

Once the json has been retrieved it is converted into a python object with:

```
    ...
    data = json.loads(data)
    ...
```

Assuming this works correctly the required items can be picked out of this object and added to the context:

**EDITED**

```
    ....
    forecast = data['Forecast']
    context["LowTemp"] = forecast["LowTemp"]
    context["HighTemp"] = forecast["HighTemp"]
    context["Date"] = forecast["Date"]
    return context
```

Comment: Thanks I tried your way, but I'm having an error for this:  File "/home/drcongo/django_lab/weatherwebapp/src/forecastApp/views.py", line 59, in get_context_data
    forecast = data['cityId']['Forecasts']

Comment: There are some differences between the screen shot and the pasted json. Does `forecast = data['Forecast']` work? The screen shot has no final 's' on 'Forecasts'.

Comment: yes it does, thanks just removed the ['cityId'] but still a bite confused about the scenario, because the json comes with many cities can't really figure out why does forecast = data['Forecast'] returns the correct data out of many cities, without actually passing the desired city ID

Comment: The python `requests` library is used to retrieve the json, this is passed a single `cityId` using the `payload`, so I'm guessing only a single forecast is returned.

Comment: thanks for your explanation and just a curious issue will it preferable to use the get_context_data() over the get_queryset() for this case